# как правильнее выводить количество комментариев

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, есть страница с новостью, и есть графа "количество комментариев"

как правильнее и лучше для оптимизации выводить это количество?

кроме таблицы с комментариями сделать дополнительное поле "comments" у новостей, и при каждом добавлении/удалении комментария изменять это значение, и затем просто выводить

или же это лишнее, и нужно выводить количество JOIN запросом  (выбором количества комментов в таблице где newsid = id новости)?

Answer (score 0):

Сказать как лучше не видя организации вашей БД сложно. Оптимально это один запрос а не два, далее, т.е. нам нужно только количество нужно использовать COUNT(*) да можно использовать JOIN можно подзапрос, можно собрать все id новостей в IN и сделать запрос

> кроме таблицы с комментариями сделать дополнительное поле "comments" у
>   новостей

Этого точно не стоит делать, их придётся постоянно обновлять, это геморно и не стоит того

Comment: а я как раз организовал свою бд так, что допустим у таблицы пользователя, есть поле news которое постоянно обновляется, я думал так будет оптимизированее, потому что при выводе количества, не нужно будет выбирать count, а просто выводить значения поля, такая же "система" и в других таблицах, думаете стоит убрать это, пока ещё не поздно?

Comment: да стоит убрать без сомнения